# Evaluate odata style conditions in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, odata

I need to evaluate odata format conditions like `apple EQ banana` in nodejs. I can write custom logic for basic conditions but for complex ones it might be too much.
Is there any library available to do that ?

I tried a few libraries but none of them support evaluation. they only support building queries.
Libraries I looked at - [odata-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-query) and [odata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-query)